# Typescript module creation AMD vs Common JS

Tags: module, typescript, amd, commonjs

Can any Typescript experts clarify when and why you would choose AMD vs Common JS for module creation when using Typescript?

Answer (score 19):

AMD is used in the browser (e.g RequireJS) : reason is it allows parallel download of files as network latency is a major bottleneck.

CommonJS is used in the server (e.g. nodejs) where files can be read from disk upfront, but you don't want to read a file till you try to use the code it contains.

Here is a video on the subject that further explains this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0

Answer (score 9):

Are you using require.js? Use AMD

Are you using node.js? Use CommonJS

Don't know what those are? Not using either of them? Don't use external modules.

Comment: This would be more helpful for beginners if a bit more explanation were included, especially along for the "Don't use external modules" advice.