# define is not defined, amd-loader vs CommonJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, protractor, visual-studio-2015, node-modules

I am working on first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12958944/492258)

When I compile main.ts to js

```
require("amd-loader");
import someModule = require('../mymodule')
var someClass  = new someModule.MyNamespace.MyClass();
```

it becomes:

```
define(["require", "exports", '../mymodule'], function (require, exports, someModule) {
    require("amd-loader");
    var someClass = new someModule.MyNamespace.MyClass();
});
```

then it gives me `define is not defined` error

When I modify it as below, error goes away.

```
require("amd-loader");
define(["require", "exports", '../mymodule'], function (require, exports, someModule) {
    var someClass = new someModule.MyNamespace.MyClass();
});
```

Then I  get `Cannot read property 'MyClass' of undefined` error

How can I get fix these error and get it work as expected as mentioned in that [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12958944/492258)?

My environment is Visual Studio 2015 and I compile with AMD options as module system(obviously I tried each options). I am doing angular protractor e2e tests

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load external AMD module using Typescript 1.5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964196/how-to-load-external-amd-module-using-typescript-1-5)

Comment: @DavidSherret But it is talking about `TypeScript HTML application` and mine is protractor test project

Answer (score 1):

As said by basarat at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20410528/492258), CommonJS should be used in this case.

In Visual Studio 2015 version 14.0.23.107.0, it seems TypeScript Module System options does not work, and it compiles always with whatever any one selected

[image]

So following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29284459/492258) CommonJS can be selected.

And voila it compile in with CommonJS and works as expected